# Somar o valor total de duas colunas, subtrair, e retornar mesmo que seja negativo MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tenho esta seguinte query:

```
SELECT FORMAT(SUM(receitas_dia) - SUM(despesas_dia),2,'de_DE') AS saldo_efetivo
FROM
  (SELECT SUM(r.valor_receita) AS receitas_dia,

     (SELECT SUM(d.valor_despesa)
      FROM despesas AS d
      WHERE d.pago = 1 AND d.data_vencimento = r.data_vencimento
        AND d.id_usuario = r.id_usuario) AS despesas_dia
   FROM receitas AS r
   WHERE r.recebido = 1 AND YEAR(r.data_vencimento) <= '2017'
     AND MONTH(r.data_vencimento) <= '06'
     AND r.id_usuario = 1
   GROUP BY r.data_vencimento) AS receita_despesas
```

Funciona bem se o valor da receita for maior que o da despesa... Mas se o valor da receita for menor, ele não retorna o valor negativo, e sim `NULL`.
Como faço pra que mesmo que a receita seja menor, ele faça a subtração e retorne o valor real negativo. (Campos do tipo DECIMAL).

**@EDIT:**
Minha query final:

```
SELECT 
 FORMAT(SUM(t.valor),2,'de_DE') AS saldo_efetivo
FROM (
 SELECT
    d.valor_despesa*-1 AS valor,
    d.data_vencimento,
    d.pago AS realizado,
    d.id_usuario
 FROM despesas AS d

 UNION

 SELECT
   r.valor_receita,
   r.data_vencimento,
   r.recebido AS realizado,
   r.id_usuario
 FROM receitas AS r
) t WHERE YEAR(t.data_vencimento) <= 2017
     AND MONTH(t.data_vencimento) <= 06
     AND t.realizado = 1
     AND t.id_usuario = 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que na verdade acontece, é que, quando há um dia em que não houve despesa, ou não houve receitas, a coluna é retornada como `null`, ao executar uma operação com a coluna `null` o resultado será `null`.

Voce pode utilizar o `coalesce` ou `ifnull` para tratar essas condições:

```
SELECT FORMAT(COALESCE(SUM(receitas_dia),0) - COALESCE(SUM(despesas_dia),0),2,'de_DE') AS saldo_previsto
FROM
  (SELECT SUM(coalesce(r.valor_receita,0)) AS receitas_dia,

 (SELECT SUM(coalesce(d.valor_despesa,0))
  FROM despesas AS d
  WHERE d.pago = 1 AND d.data_vencimento = r.data_vencimento
    AND d.id_usuario = r.id_usuario) AS despesas_dia


 FROM receitas AS r
   WHERE r.recebido = 1 AND YEAR(r.data_vencimento) <= '2017'
     AND MONTH(r.data_vencimento) <= '06'
     AND r.id_usuario = 1
   GROUP BY r.data_vencimento) AS receita_despesas
```

**Edit:**

Bem, analisando o seu código e sua necessidade, percebo que o problema não é exatamente o fato de uma coluna vir null, mas sim, que você só traz o valor da despesa para o dia que teve receita, usando um subselect de despesas, dentro de um subselect de receitas. Além de dar um GROUP BY em uma coluna que não é exibida na query.

Acreditando que sua necessidade, seja ter a data e o saldo para esta data, alterei sua query. Veja se atende:

```
SELECT 
 SUM(t.valor)
From (
 Select 
    d.valor_despesa*-1 as valor,
    d.data_vencimento,
d.pago as recebido,
d.id_usuario
 FROM despesas d


 UNION

 SELECT
   r.valor_receita,
   r.data_vencimento,
   r.recebido,
   r.id_usuario
 FROM receitas 
) t WHERE t.recebido = 1 AND YEAR(t.data_vencimento) <= 2017
     AND MONTH(t.data_vencimento) <= 06
     AND WHERE t.recebido = 1 AND YEAR(t.data_vencimento) <= 2017
     AND MONTH(t.data_vencimento) <= 06
     AND t.id_usuario = 1
```

Mas atenção, usando o where dessa forma, o banco irá carregar todos os dados das duas tabelas para depois filtrar. Em poucos registros, sem problemas, em muitos, pode ser um grande problema de desempenho

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que se você não tiver receita o valor retornado será `NULL`. Utilize a função `IFNULL` para contornar:

```
SELECT IFNULL(FORMAT(SUM(receitas_dia), 0) - IFNULL(SUM(IFNULL(despesas_dia, 0)),2,'de_DE'), 0) AS saldo_previsto
FROM
  (SELECT SUM(IFNULL(r.valor_receita, 0)) AS receitas_dia,

     (SELECT SUM(IFNULL(d.valor_despesa, 0))
      FROM despesas AS d
      WHERE d.pago = 1 AND d.data_vencimento = r.data_vencimento
        AND d.id_usuario = r.id_usuario) AS despesas_dia
   FROM receitas AS r
   WHERE r.recebido = 1 AND YEAR(r.data_vencimento) <= '2017'
     AND MONTH(r.data_vencimento) <= '06'
     AND r.id_usuario = 1
   GROUP BY r.data_vencimento) AS receita_despesas
```

Comment: o `IFNULL` deveria estar dentro do `SUM` caso contrário, sempre irá retornar 0 quando alguma linha for `NULL` e não é isso o desejado

Comment: Dessa maneira está apenas alterando o NULL para 0. Quero que retorne o valor negativo caso o resultado da subtração seja negativo.

Comment: E se não houver nenhum registro irá retornar null. Na realidade se vc analisar o objetivo da tabela dele, não deveria haver valores nulos

Comment: @EduardoHenrique testa agora. Fiz uma alteração

Comment: é, não entendo a necessidade de fazer uma tabela pra despesas e outra pra receitas, se tudo é movimento e deve ser somado depois

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!
Ainda está retornando 0 desta maneira...

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Existem várias colunas para ambas as tabelas... Na tabela de despesas existem colunas a mais do que na tabela receitas.

Comment: @EduardoHenrique tudo bem, ficaria mais fácil ignorar algumas colunas não utilizadas em uma tabela, do que ficar somando duas tabelas diferentes. Mas aí já é uma questão de modelagem, não vem ao caso